# How to connect Docker PHP container to MySql container?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, windows-10, dockerfile

I have created a docker container with `MySQL`:

```
docker run --name mysqlfordocker -p3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password_db-d mysql
```

It works as expected.

It is used by  `MySQLWorckbech` and `PHP` application which are not in the container with `MySQL`:

```
//CONNECTION BY PHP APPLICATION NOT IN CONTAINER
$servername = "127.0.0.1:3307";
$username_db = "username_db";
$password_db = "password_db";
$db = "db";
```

The `Dockerfile` for my `PHP` application is:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_pgsql pdo_mysql

COPY / /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Then I created a container with my `PHP application`:

```
docker run –d –p 5000:80 myphpapplication
```

The `PHP application` runs, but it has issues with database connection to `MySQL` container.

I tried to configure a connection `servername` in a different way but without any luck:

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1:3307";
$servername = "locahosto:3307";
$servername = "10.0.75.1:3307";  //DockerNAT
$servername = "172.17.0.2:3307"; //Ip by docker inspect mysql
```

Could you please help me on this?

Ps.
[image]

Comment: @PratheeshM I attached now the docker ps screeshot

Comment: Can you show the actual connect PHP statement (depending on the method of connection, you sometimes specify the port as a separate parameter)?  As for IP address - you should be able to use '172.17.0.1' (or .2)

Comment: @NigelRen Do you suggest  to separate port parameter  ?

Comment: Mysqli connections usually have the port as the 5th paramter (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php).

Comment: @NigelRen add your suggest as an answer with example

Comment: In your command `docker run --name mysqlfordocker -p3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password_db-d mysql` can you put space between -p option and ports . Not sure if that can make difference. Also try with the ipv4 IP address to connect from you host machine and not NAT or docker IP.
Also login into container and paste out put of /etc/hosts file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this, one is getting the right IP address of the container.  Either the actual IP address should work- 172.17.0.2, but you should also be able to use 172.17.0.1.

Also you normally put the port number as a separate parameter...

```
$servername = "172.17.0.1";
$username_db = "username_db";
$password_db = "password_db";
$db = "db";
$port= = 3307;   

$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username_db, $password_db, $db, $port);
```